# Can Smart Contract access Data of other Blockchains?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, cardano

Lets say i created an erc20 token. Now i want to make a smart contract that sends 1 coin to a user if they have X coins on another blockchain like bitcoin. Would that work? Can i read data from other blockchains using a cardano/ethereum/any other smart contract?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some bridge applications that allow you to perform cross-chain operations (mostly run by exchanges). But these are operated on a different layer, unrelated to smart contracts.

---

What you're asking is not possible if you want to stick strictly to smart contracts.

However, you can use the [oracle](https://medium.com/@teexofficial/what-are-oracles-smart-contracts-the-oracle-problem-911f16821b53) pattern. Create an off-chain app (the oracle) that listens to transactions from your contract to a specific address. Each transaction (from your contract to the target address) will trigger an action in the off-chain app - e.g. reading Bitcoin data. The oracle then sends another transaction to your smart contract, passing it the off-chain data.